# Access private map through reflection in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection

I need to access a private map for unit testing but unable to do that.

**Main class:**

```
public class TestMe{
private Map<String, SomeObject> testMap = new HashMap<String, SomeObject>();
}
```

**Unit Test:**

```
public class TestMeTester{
   public testTestMe(){
      TestMe obj = new TestMe();

      Class clazz = obj.getClass();

      Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("testMap");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      Map<String, SomeObject> refMap = (HashMap<String, SomeObject>) field.get(new HashMap<String, Object>());
            System.out.println("==>" + refMap);
   }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Map field com.xx.TestMe.testMap to java.util.HashMap
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must invoke `Field.get()` with the `TestMe` object.

```
TestMe obj = new TestMe(); 
....
Map<String, SomeObject> refMap = (HashMap<String, SomeObject>) = field.get(obj);
```

Your code invokes `Field.get()` on a new instance of `HashMap`.

```
field.get(new HashMap<String, Object>()); // This will not work in your case
```

EDIT to comment: *This is not working.*

I tried to figure out what could not be working. This is my test code and it works.

```
public class TestMeTester {

    public static class TestMe {
        private Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalAccessException, SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {
        TestMe obj = new TestMe();
        Class clazz = obj.getClass();
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("testMap");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, String> refMap = (HashMap<String, String>) field.get(obj);
        System.out.println("==>" + refMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JSS I added my code that I used to find out what could not be working. But it works. Could you explain what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access your map for unit testing, then add a default-access getter method. Nothing wrong with writing your code to support unit testing:

```
Map<String, SomeObject> getTestMap() {...}
```

Reflection should be your last alternative, typically when you have no opportunity to edit the target class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do

```
Map<String, SomeObject> refMap = (HashMap<String, SomeObject>) field.get(obj);
```

As shown by the following (working) code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {
    static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        Field x = f.getClass().getDeclaredField("x");
        x.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("Before: " + x.get(f)); // prints 1
        x.set(f, (Integer)2);
        System.out.println("After: " + x.get(f)); // prints 2
    }
}

class Foo {
    private Integer x = 1;
}
```

Otherwise you're trying to retrieve the `testMap` field of a `HashMap`, which doesn't exist.

Besides your issue accessing a private field via reflection, writing unit tests that rely on these sort of implementation details (ie the presence of a private field) are likely to break very soon. I would suggest to have a look at the following links:

http://xunitpatterns.com/Fragile%20Test.html#Overcoupled%20Software
http://xunitpatterns.com/Principles%20of%20Test%20Automation.html#Use%20the%20Front%20Door%20First

Comment: @JSS Please have a look at my last update. My snippet of code should just work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

So I just figured it out through some trial and error with my code:

If you're like me and you have to use Java Reflection, then read on, otherwise, @Duncan already mentioned an efficient way by just making a method for getting your HashMap for testing purposes.

Now, what you're going to do is:

1. Declare type Field to be your reference to your private Map and initialize your class that contains the
   `private Map: Field map = ClassName.class.getDeclaredField(String "name of map")`
2. Set your Field instance to accessible: `map.setAccessible(true)`
3. Since you know your Field is a Map, you can cast the Object to Map and then call Map methods on the Field argument Object you pass through your
   `Field instance.get(obj) call. (Map) map.get(classNameInstance)`
4. In testing I was getting an error stating assertEquals(Object, Object) for my case. To avoid this problem I simply casted it to primitive. I also checked and it works for String too, so inductively it should work for all other defined Objects.

Here's a coded example for reference. In my case I had to use a HashMap that mapped Strings to Integers and my final casting error was that I could not compare an int and an Integer using assertEquals, so I casted Integer to int:

```
public class KeywordCollection{
  private static HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  //Etc. for KeywordCollection, only the private initialization is relevant
}

public void addTests() throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException,
        Exception, IllegalAccessException {
    KeywordCollection keys1 = new KeywordCollection();
    Field map = KeywordCollection.class.getDeclaredField("keywordTable");
    map.setAccessible(true);

    // Test if add works trivially
    assertTrue(keys1.addKeyword("First"));
    assertFalse(keys1.addKeyword("First"));
    assertFalse(keys1.addKeyword("FIrST"));
    assertTrue(keys1.addKeyword("Inductive"));
    assertTrue(keys1.addKeyword("Not in keys2"));
    System.out.println(map.get(keys1).toString());
    output: {Not in keys2=3, Inductive=2, First=1}

    //For getting values
    assertEquals(1,(int) ((HashMap<String, Integer>) map.get(keys1)).get("First"));
```

So you can see that using the cast call `(HashMap<String, Integer>) map.get(keys1)`
I set the Field map instance to reference my object class KeywordCollection which has my HashMap, then casted it from an Object to a HashMap so I could access my HashMap methods. Otherwise it was only accessing Object methods. Using this, you can run tests on your map as you would normally (accessing map.keySet, contains, get(key), etc. etc.)

Also, don't worry about all the exceptions. I do my coding in Eclipse so it gives me warnings of un-handled exceptions, so I have it set to throw the exceptions that would be thrown by the methods according to their API. They pertain to the Field variable if you're curious, but if you know what your field is in the method you are calling then you should not have an issue using this method.

NoSuchFieldException means there was no variable by that name your passed in the class you called

and IllegalAccessException means you did not have permission to access that Field (i.e. you did not setAccessible to true)

Also don't forget your imports. for Field you import java.lang.reflect.Field (I like to use *)

Hope it helps.